# View .tiff file with Xfinium (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, cross-platform, pdf-viewer

I am using Xfinium to create and view a pdf file in my cross platform mobile app. Using Xfinium's PdfDocumentRenderer object, I can convert the pdf file to a miltipage .tiff file, but I don't know how to view the .tiff file.

I'm using the Viewer Edition of Xfinium, but I can't find any documentation on how to utilize the viewing capabilities.

Comment: are you sure Xfinium can actually view TIFF files?  Have you tried contacting their support to ask?

Comment: @Jason I'm not sure, but the only method I could find was one that converted a pdf to tiff. I have not but that's what I'm going to do right now